# Java - Write a program using the following static void methods

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods, netbeans-8

Write the following methods to

1. read the content of an array of 5 doubles
   public static double[] readingArray()
2. find and print: the sum of the elements in an array of 5 double
   public static void sum(double [] array)
3. find and print: the average of the elements in an array of 5 doubles
   pubic static void avg (double [] array)
   In the main method

- invoke readingArray and enter the following numbers 50 20 10 40 30
- invoke sum
- invoke avg.

I do not what I am doing wrong with the methods public static void sum and public static avg(double [] array).
Buy I cannot print the results.

run:
Reading:
Please enter array elements: 50 20 10 40 30
The Sum:
The avg:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Quiz10_Op2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] array;   
            
        System.out.println("Reading: "); 
        array = readingArray();   
            
        System.out.println("The Sum: " ); 
        sum(array); 
    
        System.out.println("The avg: " );
        avg(array); 
    }
        
    public static double[] readingArray(){   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double array[] = new double[5];
        System.out.print("Please enter array elements: ");
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        return array;
        }
    public static void sum(double [] array){
        double sum = array[0];  
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
            sum = sum + array[i];
        }
    }
    public static void avg (double [] array){
        double sum = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
            sum = sum + array[i];
        }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to print values.

```
public static void sum(double [] array){
    double sum = array[0];  
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum); // This line
}
public static void avg (double [] array){
    double sum = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum/array.length); // This line
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now is printing.